# I can't understand a certain line in the following piece of code

Tags: java, equals

I can't figure out what the point is of the 'final Person other' line.
On the first conditional test a control is executed to check if the parameter isn't null ,which makes sense to me.
Secondly ,if the classes are identical so a comparison can be made, which again makes sense to me . But than I'm lost because I don't understand the necessity to create another Person object and use that as a reference.

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.surname, other.surname)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring `other` as `final`, it means that you can not change the value once it has been set.

The reason you're casting to a `Person` object is because, the parameter of is type `Object`. That means you can get all of the methods in the `Object` class. By casting it to `Person`, you can access all of the methods in the `Person` class. The same functionality could be achieved by:

```
((Person)obj).personMethod();
```

Comment: So if it hadnt been cast to a person ,than I would have been unable to get its instance variables as well?

Comment: Correct. Because the reference type was `Object`.

Comment: @christopher there is no object creation, only a cast.

Comment: @assylias Apologies; semantic mistake on my part. I'll change now.